# Restrict page media allowedExtensions TYPO3 9.5.x

Tags: typo3, fal

How can I restrict `allowedExtention` just for `$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['media']`? But not using `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']` as it will add restriction for all FAL fields.

I found class

```
class ImageManipulationElement extends AbstractFormElement
{
    /**
     * Default element configuration
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $defaultConfig = [
        'file_field' => 'uid_local',
        'allowedExtensions' => null, // default: $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
```

Looks like should be something like:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['media']['config']['overrideChildTca']['allowedExtensions'] = 'jpg, jpeg';
```

Hard way will drope all usefull things for this field.

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['media'] = [
             'exclude' => true,
             'label' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.media',
             'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
                 'media',
                 [], 'jpg, jpeg'
             )
         ];
```

So not is our way. I need just some override like

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['media']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']...['allowedExtention'] = 'jpg, jpeg';
```

Who know knows how to do this?

Comment: Have a look into \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig().
'allowedFileExtensions' is used in 'filter -> parameters'. So a simple $GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['media']['config']['filter']['parameters'][''allowedFileExtensions'] = 'jpg' should work.

Comment: Forgot an array hierarchy below 'filter': $GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['media']['config']['filter'][0]['parameters']['allowedFileExtensions'] = 'jpg'

Comment: @JulianHofmann For me $GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['media']['config']['filter'][0]['parameters']['allowedFileExtensions'] = 'jpg,jpeg'; have no effect but i have found in this way
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['media']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']['uid_local']['config']['appearance']['elementBrowserAllowed']='jpg,jpeg'; and this work. Thx for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After small searching I found this example:

```
$allowExtensions = 'jpg,jpeg';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['media']['config']['filter'][0]['parameters']['allowedFileExtensions'] = '$allowExtensions; 
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['media']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']['uid_local']['config']['appearance']['elementBrowserAllowed']= $allowExtensions;
```

added to typo3conf/ext/myext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/pages.php